# War das gesprochene Deutsch vor 500-1000 Jahren ähnlicher dem Hoch- oder dem Plattdeutsch?

Tags: standard-german, dialect, history

Ich weiß nicht, ob es eine genaue Antwort auf diese Frage gibt, aber ich möchte gerne wissen, wenn man heutige deutsche Dialekten mit Altdeutsch vergleicht. Welcher Dialekt blieb dieser Sprache am ähnlichsten?

Comment: In Bremen oder Augsburg, vor 500 oder 1000 Jahren? Aber wenn jemand die Frage zum Anlass für einen Überblick über die Geschichte des Deutschen nimmt, der sich nicht aus Hochdeutsche beschränkt, dann bin ich auch interessiert.

Comment: "Das Altdeutsche" gibts überhaupt nicht. Es war mehr in Dialekte aufgeteilt als das moderne Deutsch. Weil es ja auch kein Fernsehn gab.

Answer (score 2):

Die korrekte Antwort auf diese Frage lautet: **Das kommt darauf an.**

Diese Frage unterstellt nämlich etwas, das gar nicht zutrifft: In der Frage steht: *»das ... Deutsch«.* Es wird so getan, als gäbe es nur ein einziges Deutsch. Das ist jetzt, im 21. Jahrhundert, nicht der Fall, und es war in den Jahrhunderten davor noch viel weniger der Fall.

Die Amtssprachen der Staaten Deutschland, Österreich und Schweiz sind drei verschiedene Sprachen. Diese drei Sprachen sind einander zwar sehr ähnlich und werden in den nächsten Jahrzehnten noch viel ähnlicher werden, und sie verwenden (bis auf wenige Ausnahmen) auch dieselben Rechtschreibregeln, aber Vokabular (Schweiz: *Abwart,* Österreich: *Hausbesorger,* Deutschland: *Hausmeister*), Grammatik (Ö: *Ich bin gelegen.* D: *Ich habe gelegen.*) und Aussprache (*»Kaffee«*: Ö letzten Silbe lange und betont, D: letze Silbe kurz und unbetont) sind dennoch nach wie vor unterschiedlich. Alle drei Varietäten sind standardisiert, dürfen also nicht mit Dialekten verwechselt werden.

In der Vergangenheit waren die Unterschiede noch viel ausgeprägter. Eine einzelne deutsche Sprache hat es niemals gegeben. Vielmehr gab es zur Zeit der Völkerwanderung in dem Gebiet Europas, das bei grober Näherung dem heutigen deutschen Sprachraum entspricht, viele verschiedene germanische Völker: Es gab die Langobarden, Alemannen und Bajuwaren im Süden und etwas weiter im Norden die Franken und Sachsen, daneben noch Goten, Friesen und weitere andere germanische Völker.

Sie alle lebten an unterschiedlichen Orten und sprachen unterschiedliche Sprachen bzw. Dialekte. Am ehesten kann man sich das als ein Kontinuum vorstellen: Eine Tagesreise vom eigenen Wohnort entfernt (also ca. 30 km entfernt, im Gebirge weniger, in ebenen Gebieten mehr) traf man auf Menschen, deren Sprache zwar ein klein wenig anders war, aber man konnte sich problemlos über alle Themen unterhalten. Nahm man eine mehrwöchige Reise auf sich, wurde die Verständigung hingegen deutlich schwieriger.

An einigen Stellen veränderte sich die Sprache stärker, während man anderswo auch nach einer fünftägigen Reise kaum eine Veränderung der Sprache bemerkten konnte. Jene Grenzen, bei deren Überquerung sich die Sprache stärker veränderte als anderswo, nennt man Isoglossen, und es gibt sie heute noch:

- [Benrather Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benrather_Linie) (maken/machen-Linie)
  Sie trennt eigentlich nur jene Gebiete voneinander, in denen im Dialekt das Verb *machen* entweder als *»maken«* oder als *»machen«* ausgesprochen wird, aber die ik/ich-Linie, die dat/das-Linie,die Dorp/Dorf-Linie und die hebben/haben-Line sowie viele ähnliche Linien haben fast denselben geographischen Verlauf und werden daher zu einer Linie zusammengefasst. Diese Linie beginnt im Westen bei Aachen und verläuft von dort in ostnordöstlicher Richtung bis Berlin und darüber hinaus bis zur polnischen Grenze.
- [Speyerer Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyerer_Linie_(Isoglosse)) (Appel/Apfel-Linie; *»Äppeläquator«*)
  Diese Linie beginnt im Westen ungefähr bei Karlsruhe, geht von dort in nordöstlicher Richtung bis ungefähr Eisenach/Erfurt und von dort in südöstlicher Richtung an Plauen vorbei bis nach Tschechien.

Es gibt noch viele anderen Isoglossen, die den deutschen Sprachraum durchziehen, aber die beiden oben genannten sind die beiden wichtigsten, denn sie teilen den deutschen Sprachraum in drei relativ klar unterscheidbare Gebiete, deren Ursprung in der Besiedelung des Gebiets durch unterschiedliche Völker zu suchen ist.

In dem Gebiet nördlich der Benrather Linie wurden deutsche Dialekte gesprochen, die man zum Niederdeutschen zählt, während man die Dialekte, die südlich davon beheimatet sind, zum Hochdeutsch zusammenfasst. Der Teil *»Nieder«* bzw *»Hoch«* bezieht sich daher auf die mittlere Seehöhe der Gebiete. Der alpine Süden liegt geographisch höher als der an Nord- und Ostsee grenzende Norden.

Das Hochdeutsche Gebiet ist durch die Speyerer Linie weiter unterteilt: Zwischen Benrather und Speyerer Linie liegt das mitteldeutsche Sprachgebiet, südlich davon das oberdeutsche.

Und jedes dieser Gebiete ist selbst wiederum in sprachliche Teilgebiete unterteilt, z.B. zerfällt der Oberdeutsche Sprachraum in einen alemannischen Teil im Westen und einen bairischen Teil im Osten, und das geht eben auf die Besiedlung dieser Gebiete durch die Alemannen und Bajuwaren zurück. Die ebenfalls deutschsprachigen Langobarden, die zur Zeit der Völkerwanderung ebenfalls im oberdeutschen Sprachraum lebten (im Gebiet des heutigen Norditalien) sind um das Jahr 1000 herum ausgestorben, und mit ihnen auch ihre Sprache.

Ich hebe die Gliederung des oberdeutschen Sprachraums deswegen hervor, weil dort die Staatsgebiete der Schweiz und Österreichs liegen, wo die meisten deutsche Muttersprachler außerhalb Deutschlands leben. Während also in Deutschland nach wie vor ein Dialektkontinuum besteht, dass sich in zum Teil recht unterschiedlichen Dialekten manifestiert, die ihren Ursprung in vielen verschiedenen germanischen Völkern haben, ist der deutschsprachige Teil der Schweiz rein alemannisch und 96% aller deutschen Muttersprachler in Österreich tragen das Erbe bairischer Dialekte weiter (die restlichen 4 % ganz im Westen sind Alemannen). Und das wiederum hat Einfluss auf die Alltagssprache und in weiterer Folge auf die oben erwähnten drei verschiedenen Standards der deutschen Sprache.

---

In der Frage wurde der Begriff *»Altdeutsch«* verwendet. Dieser Begriff ist sprachwissenschaftlich nicht definiert. Es gibt aber *Althochdeutsch, Mittelhochdeutsch* und *Neuhochdeutsch.* Damit versucht man eine zeitliche Gliederung in der Entwicklung der hochdeutschen Sprache zu beschrieben. Daneben gibt es noch *Altsächsisch* und *Niederdeutsch* als zeitliche Gliederung der niederdeutschen Sprache:

- **Althochdeutsch**
  Damit meint man die Gesamtheit der hochdeutschen Dialekte, so wie sie zwischen ca. 750 und 1050 südlich der Benrather Linie gesprochen wurden. Damit meint man also nur Langobardisch, Alemannisch, Bairisch, Fränkisch.
  Tatsächlich hat damals aber niemand die Sprache *Althochdeutsch* gesprochen. Das ist nur eine theoretische Dachsprache der genannten Sprachen bzw. Dialekte. Das Althochdeutsch aus dem Gebiet Bozens unterschied sich daher deutlich vom Kölner Althochdeutsch.
- **Altsächsisch**
  Damit meint man die Verallgemeinerung der Sprachen und Dialekte, die vor allem die Sachsen und Angeln nördlicher der Benrather Linie gesprochen haben, und zwar ungefähr zur selben Zeit, als südlich davon Althochdeutsche Dialekte verwendet wurden. Aus Altsächsisch entstanden Niederdeutsch und Niederländisch. Als die Angeln dann gemeinsam mit ein paar Sachsen auf die britischen Inseln auswanderten und dort auf keltische Einflüsse stießen, wandelte sich die sächsisch-**a**nglische Sprache zur **e**nglischen Sprache.
- **Mittelhochdeutsch**
  Das ist die Verallgemeinerung der Dialekte bzw. Sprachen, die im Hochmittelalter (ca. 1050 - 1350) südlicher der Benrather Linie gesprochen wurden. Auch hier gilt: Mittelhochdeutsch war niemandes Muttersprache. Die Menschen sprachen Fränkisch, Bairisch und Alemannisch, und Mittelhochdeutsch versucht nur die Gemeinsamkeiten dieser Dialekte/Sprachen zu erfassen.
- **Niederdeutsch**
  Der Übergang von Altsächsisch zu Niederdeutsch erfolge ungefähr im 12. Jahrhundert. Soweit mir bekannt ist, gibt es zwischen dem 12. Jahrhundert und der Gegenwart keine weitere etablierte zeitliche Gliederung der Niederdeutschen Dialekte/Sprachen. Niederdeutsch existiert auch heute noch mit vielen Millionen Sprechern im Norden Deutschlands. Ob man das Niederdeutsche als einen Dialekt der deutschen Sprache oder als eine eigenständige (nichtstandardisierte) Sprache auffassen sollte, ist Gegenstand einer andauernden Debatte, wobei es meiner Wahrnehmung nach eine starke Tendenz gibt, das Niederdeutsche als Sprache anzusehen.
- **Neuhochdeutsch**
  Nach ca. 1350 spricht man südlich der Benrather Linie von einer Neuhochdeutschen Sprache, die aber nach wie vor (bis heute) in unterschiedlichen geographischen Regionen stark von den zugrundeliegenden Dialekten Fränkisch, Alemannisch und Bairisch beeinflusst ist.

  Erwähnenswert ist auch, dass die Schriftsprache, in der Beamte und andere Schreiber Dokumente verfassten, nicht exakt mit der Sprache übereinstimmte, in der sich dieselben Personen innerhalb der Familie oder mit Freunden unterhielten. Das, was man als Neuhochdeutsch (aber auch Mittel- und Alt-Hochdeutsch) bezeichnet, ist diese Schriftsprache. Es gab immer schon Bestrebungen, diese Schriftsprache über dem gesamten deutschen Sprachraum zu vereinheitlichen, und hier sind vor allem die deutsche Übersetzung der Bibel von Martin Luther und die sächsische Kanzleisprache zu erwähnen. Diese Versuche die Deutsche Schriftsprache zu vereinheitlichen hatten auch Einfluss auf das gesprochene Deutsch, führten aber auch dazu, dass es in einigen Gebieten des deutschen Sprachraums zu einem deutlichen Auseinanderdriften von gesprochenem und geschriebenem Deutsch kam, das heute am stärksten in der Schweiz ausgeprägt ist, wo einer Umfrage zufolge mehr als 3/4 der deutschen Muttersprachler das standardisierte Schriftdeutsch als Fremdsprache empfinden, während die in der Schweiz vorherrschenden gesprochenen Dialekte als Muttersprache empfunden werden.

Comment: Das ist, mit Verlaub, Unsinn und versaut die ansonsten schöne Antwort: *Die Amtssprachen der Staaten Deutschland, Österreich und Schweiz sind drei verschiedene Sprachen.* (Siehe österreichisches Verfassungsgesetz, Artikel 8, deutsches Verwaltungsverfahrensgesetz §23, schweizerische Verfassung, Art. 70). Ich verstehe, dass das bei Dir durch einen starken Lokalpatriotismus geprägt wird, aber jeder Linguist wird dir (heftig) widersprechen, dass es sich hier um drei verschiedene Sprachen handelt. Ausserdem, (wenn schon) dann vergiß bitte die armen Belgier, Liechtensteiner und Luxemburger nicht....

Comment: ... die müssten dann doch nach deiner Ansicht auch jeder ein eigenes Deutsch verdient haben...

Comment: Die Amtssprachen von D, Ö und CH sind streng genommen Standardvarietäten, aber ich wollte meine ohnehin lange Antwort nicht noch mit ausführlichen Definitionen überfrachten. Unterschiedlich und standardisiert sind sie allemal (z.B. Ö: Jänner sonst Januar, D: Abitur sonst Matura, CH Steueramt sonst Finanzamt). Die Amtssprache von Liechtenstein ist schweizerisches Standarddeutsch (Januar, Matura, Steueramt), das Deutsch, das Amtssprache in Italien (in Südtirol) ist, ist österreichisches Standarddeutsch (Jänner, Matura, Finanzamt), und in allen anderen Ländern, in denen Deutsch eine ...

Comment: ... offizielle Amtssprache ist, wird deutsches Deutsch verwendet (Januar, Abitur, Finanzamt). Deutsch ist auch eine der 24 Amtssprachen der EU, und auch die EU verwendet deutsches Deutsch (Januar, Abitur, Finanzamt), wobei es hier Sonderregelungen für insgesamt 23 Austriazismen gibt, die 1995 beim Beitritt Österreichs dem EU-Amtsdeutsch hinzugefügt wurden. (Man hat damals übrigens ausschließlich kulinarische Begriffe zum Amtdeutsch hinzugefügt.)

Comment: Auch ohne lange Definitionen kann man das Kind doch beim richtigen Namen nennen ohne das es länger oder unverständlich würde ... Varianten des Standarddeutsch oder Standardvarietäten des Deutsch.

Comment: "Die ebenfalls deutschsprachigen Langobarden, die zur Zeit der Völkerwanderung ebenfalls im oberdeutschen Sprachraum lebten (im Gebiet des heutigen Norditalien) sind um das Jahr 1000 herum ausgestorben, und mit ihnen auch ihre Sprache." Das ist missverständlich ausgedrückt. Die Langobarden sind (nicht ganz freiwillig und genauso wie z.B. viele durch die deutsche Ostsiedlung assimilierte slavische Völker) in anderen Völkern aufgegangen.

Comment: Eine gute Antwort heißt nicht immer eine lange Antwort.

Comment: Gegenrede: Ich gehe davon aus, dass sich die Amts- und Verkehrssprachen der Schweiz von den anderen beiden Standardvarietäten wegentwickeln werden und wir mittelfristig eine neue Schweizer Sprache erleben werden. Also, du vielleicht nicht mehr, ich möglicherweise, die Generationen nach mir bestimmt. Spannend wird dann sein, was im Vorarlberg sprachlich passiert.

Comment: @Jan: Die Entwicklung in der Schweiz ist tatsächlich sehr schwer vorherzusagen. Deutschschweizer sprechen und schreiben zwei verschiedene Sprachen. Das sogenannte Schriftdeutsch wird - wie in Österreich - sehr stark durch das deutschländische Deutsch beeinflusst. Auf dem österreichischen Buch- und Zeitschriftenmarkt ist es sehr schwer, ein Produkt in der eigenen Sprachvarietät zu finden. Als Österreicher ist man gewohnt, in Büchern und Zeitschriften *»Januar«, »Abitur«* und *»es **hat** gelegen«* zu lesen, und ich vermute, dass das in ...

Comment: ... der Schweiz nicht viel anders sein wird. Dadurch sind in den letzen 30 Jahren viele ur-österreichische Begriffe wie *»Paradeiser«* und *»Erdäpfel«* fast vollständig aus dem Alltagswortschatz verschwunden, und es würde mich nicht wundern, wenn das schweizerische *»Poulet«* irgendwann auch vom deutsche *»Hähnchen«* verdrängt wird. Das österreichische *»Hendl«* ist vor allem in Regionen die starkem Tourismus ausgesetzt sind (und das ist halb Österreich) auch schon sehr stark vom *»Hähnchen«* bedroht. Andererseits ist in ...

Comment: ... der Schweiz ein Phänomen zu beobachten, das es anderswo nicht gibt: Eine Verschriftlichung des Dialekts in der privaten Kommunikation. Wenn sich Schweizer in Chats, Foren usw. unterhalten, schreiben sie nur selten im Schriftdeutsch. Es hat sich mittlerweile sogar schon eine Quasi-Norm für die Rechtschreibung des schweizerischen Dialekts entwickelt. Wie sich das auf das offizielle Schriftdeutsch auswirkt, wage ich nicht vorherzusagen.

Comment: Vor ein paar Jahren habe ich auf einer Schweizer Autobahnraststätte ein Benutzungshinweiseschild gesehen und gelesen, und das Deutsch war, für mich als Deutschlanddeutscher, spannend. Ich musste mir einen relevanten Teil durch Kontext erschließen. Was für mich eher in Richtung Trennung spricht.